# Static CSS files not applied to expressJS app

Tags: css, node.js

I am trying by first express web app and I am using html to render my web pages and css to style my pages.

My directory structure is as follows

```
app.js
routes/
       index.js
views/
     index.html
public/
      stylesheets/
                  style.css
```

index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Devices</title>
    <link ref="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheets/style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <h1>DEVICES</h1>
    <table>
        <tr><th>#</th><th>DID</th><th>DeviceName</th><th>OS</th><th>Version</th><th>Numbers</th></tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

I have linked the static CSS file using link tag

app.js

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var routes = require('./routes/index');
var users = require('./routes/users');

var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');

// uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
//app.use(favicon(__dirname + '/public/favicon.ico'));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'styles')));

app.use('/', routes);
app.use('/users', users);
```

please note app.set('view engine', 'jade'); is left as it is as if i give html i am getting error.

index.js

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var router = express.Router();

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {

  res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname , '../views/index.html'));
});

module.exports = router;
```

My issue is the static css file placed in public/stylesheets is not applied to my html when rendered.When I execute http://localhost:3000/stylesheets/style.css, I able to see the contents of style.css is returned.

I am not quite sure what I am doing wrong

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try changing how you set the path to your static assets.

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/styles'));
```